# Java .class files not going into bin with coderunner VScode extenstion

Tags: java, json, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCcT4.png)

I am trying to make it so instead of coderunner making .class files in src folder that it would go to the bin instead, but I'm not sure how to quiet configure the settings correctly

this is what I currently have in there

"java": "cd $dir && javac -d src $fileName && java $fileNameWithoutExt && mv $fileName.class bin/",

I tried multiple ways to go about it but I'm not sure what the correct thing to have for the settings would be

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.